# Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see https://g.co/ng/security#xss)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am working with angular cli, I have a rest api made with yii2, my problem is the following:

I have a component, which consists of a video gallery, which are youtube links (https://www.youtube.com/embed/5to1QLIxqzA). In the api I have all the urls for the component, so it looks like this:

videos.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let video of videos" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="embed-responsive-item video-noticia">
        <div class="video-responsive">
            <iframe class="responsive-iframe" width="730" height="415"
             src="{{video.url}}" title="YouTube video player"
             frameborder="0"
             allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
             encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

videos.component.ts:

```
export class VideosComponent implements OnInit {

    videos: Video[] = [];

    constructor(private data: DataService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.data.getAllVideos().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    this.data.getAllVideos().subscribe(data => this.videos = data);        
    }

}
```

in the folder of the component (videos), i have the service to call api:

data.service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

    private urlApi = 'http://localhost/web/api/web/video';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAllVideos(): Observable<Video[]> {
        return this.http.get<Video[]>(this.urlApi);
    }
}
```

And the following error is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMV9N.png)

I read in other queestions about to create a pipe with DomSanitizer, I tried but didn't work for me.
I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Inject DomSanitizer in your component's constructor

```
constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
```

Then map your videos array

```
this.data.getAllVideos().subscribe(data => {
 this.videos = data;
 this.videos = this.videos.map(video => video.url = this.this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(video.url))
}
```

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work. Shows the same error.